# python how to import a script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 by pythonwin.

I have created my own custom modules like this:

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print b,
        a, b = b, a+b

def fib2(n): # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

The file name is `fiboo.py`

Now i want to open pythonwin and import it. where should I put the `fiboo.py`?

my script path is:

```
D:\fiboo.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the module file inside [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Even better, you could create your own package. For example a package named `mytests`.

Just create a folder in your `$HOME` named `py_packages` (for example), a `mytests` folder inside it (for the package), and inside it create an empty `__init__.py` file and your module file.

Then just add your `$HOME/py_packages` folder to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and you'll be able to import it as:

```
from mytests import fiboo
```

Comment: i have no Pythonpath in my system variables. what should I do?

Comment: just create the variable

Comment: what is the value of it? Also, what is `$home`

Comment: Actually `$HOME` was for *ix. If you prefer to do so you can create the `py_packages` (or any other name) in `D:`, and then set `PYTHONPATH` to `D:/py_packages` for example.

Comment: now i am able to do this `from MyTests import Functions`. However, I can't call the function `function1()` why?

Comment: I got this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function1' is not defined`

Comment: You have imported the package `Functions`. Now to call the functions inside you should write `Functions.function1()`.

As alternative you can import the functions:

`from MyTests.Functions import function1`

Comment: yes and now i am able to do this: `Functions.function1()` and it returns and prints the correct results. But please is there anyway so I can do this `function1()` without the name of the scripts?

Comment: But maybe you should read python [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) as Henry recommends.

Comment: I was reading it and now I just found the section that I want. thank you buddy.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: if you've defined things in `fiboo.py`, then your module name is `fiboo`. You can put the *file* anywhere you want, so long as it's on your [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (or in the current working directory). Then you import it by typing `import fiboo`.

I highly recommend reading up on the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), which by the looks of it you already are, since those functions come straight from the first module example. As the example there explains: put the file in the current directory, open a command prompt in that directory, and import it.